# Distance heatmap from line

Tags: qgis, raster, distance, line

I have a line vector file and want to create raster file from it.
Here, the raster file's each pixel corresponds with shortest distance from the line.

How can I do it with QGIS ?

Comment: It is called proximity raster. First, rasterize your line vector. Then try `Raster | Analysis | Proximity (Raster Distance)` on that raster.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I rasterized line vector, but generated tiff was all black(zero values). When rasterizing, how should I set "Attribute field" ? I want "geometric" distance from line, so I don't care about attribute here though ...

Comment: Yes that is the tricky part. At the bottom of `Rasterize (vector to raster)` dialog window,  GDAL command-line is displayed. After setting up raster size (or resolution), press the edit (pencil) button to make it editable. Then manually add `-burn 100 -ot Byte`  (this 100 can be any value between 1-254) and run the tool.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried "gdal_rasterize -burn 100 -ot Byte -ts 3000 3000 -l line" and "gdal_rasterize -burn 100 -ot Byte -a VALUE -ts 3000 3000 -l line", where VALUE is selected attribute field. But still get all blacks, zeros. What's wrong ?

Comment: Please remove `-a VALUE`. Sorry, forgot to mention that part.

Comment: Thank you ! "gdal_rasterize -burn 100 -ot Byte -tr 0.001 0.001 -l line" worked for me. Before doing that, I had to clip vector data, because it covered too big area. The above command didn't work for original big vector data. Anyway, problem was solved !

Comment: Glad it worked out, and thanks for your feedback. It would be great if you can post overall workflow as your answer and accept it, when it is done.